# Question about meaning of "off highway" and "across"

Tags: word-meaning

> California residents who drive on public highway or use public parking facilities must have a California driver license, unless they are driving or operating an off-highway vehicle across the highway.

What kind if vehicle is an **off-highway**? And what does **across** here mean? Does it mean from the right of a one-lane highway to the other side left?

Comment: What is the source of your quotation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An off-highway vehicle is one that is not designed for roadways: tractors, [snowmobiles](http://peter.evans-greenwood.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/10/snowmobile.jpg), [riding lawnmowers](http://www.cpsc.gov/PageFiles/74749/05517b.jpg), [Bobcat tractors](http://www.birents.com/itemimages/6134.jpg), [ATVs](http://uncrate.com/p/2011/04/king-cobra-atv-xl.jpg), etc.

The statute you quote is basically giving an exemption for crossing the road in one of these vehicles, even without a driver's license.

For example, if I lived in California and owned a farm, and I had a 14-year-old son who drove a tractor on the farm, he would be allowed to cross the highway even without a license (but he wouldn't be allowed to drive down the highway without a license).